# JPG file not loading in webpage

Tags: html, image, web, jpeg, broken-links

I have a basic webpage that references four image files using the following code:

```
<img src="/images/SanFran.jpg" name="urbanForm" alt="urbanFormA" width="150" height="100"/>
```

(I change SanFran.jpg, to London.jpg, NewYork.jpg and Barcelona.jpg - just replacing the filename)

However, although the 4 jpegs are very similar (200 x 150 pixels) and made using a similar technique (cropping an image in Picassa), only one of the files will load (London.jpg). The other three give me a broken link message. I have checked that I am do not have misspellings numerous times, and cannot find the problem.

Is there anything that I have not considered?

(I'm using Aptana Studio on OSX and viewing it using Safari as a previewer; the same problem exists if I look at it using Firefox or Chrome)

Comment: can you link us to the page? It's easier to debug it directly.

Comment: and have you uploaded the other images? I know, potentially a silly question, but you never know...

Comment: I had a similar problem, but it affected only jpgs in IE. Some attempts to solve the problem are documented here: http://doctype.com/internet-explorer-jpg-problem

Comment: also try Ctrl-Shift+Reload a few times to force a cache clear. You never know.

Comment: Yes - all files are in my local directory 'images'. Sorry - I can't upload it anywhere at the moment.

Comment: I think the problem is a weird glitch in Aptana studio - the problem still exists. I realized now though, that this is ok in a browser (if I opened it straight from there), but if I open a browser via Aptana it does not work.

Comment: Did you get any solution in the end, btw?

Comment: @Mark Mayo - I figured out that it was a problem within Aptana Studio. It's not really a solution, more of a problem identification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try naming one of the others
   SanFran.jpg.  See what happens. 
   Might give you a clue.
2. Open them all in windows explorer,
       confirm the images themselves load
       normally and aren't corrupt.
3. Check all are in /images/
4. right click on the broken link and
   choose view image or copy image
   location.  See if where it's trying
   to access is definitely the right
   place.
5. Do the same with the working one.
       Compare and see if any differences.
6. change everything to lowercase, just
       in case (excuse pun)
7. hit ctrl+shift+reload a few times,
       and F5 a few times.
8. clear cache manually if you know how
       or have the tools.
9. Copy it to a different loacation and
       try loading them there.  Ideally a
       different computer.
10. Upload it somewhere and see if it
         works in your browser when online

Hopefully one of those may help...

Comment: Thanks Mark, I tried most of these suggestions - as I mentioned upthread the problem is with Aptana studio - not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Are all the images in the same directory?

Make all the file names lowercase, so you know that isn't the issue.

double check extensions, "jpg or jpeg or JPG or JPEG"

take it back to basics `<img src="images/filename.jpg" />`

Comment: yes - they are all in the same directory. Same problem with just <img src="" />

Comment: Is the images directory in root with your index?

Comment: yes - I can read one file from it, which is why I am certain I am referencing the directory correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the files are there, make sure the case of the filename matches (s is different than S on Linux), and then make sure .jpg is the proper extension and not .jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because your Jpegs are saved as CMYK as oppose to RGB. See this link for more detail. However this would only affect some browsers

http://www.plaveb.com/blog/cmyk-images-not-displayed-in-internet-explorer

Comment: I just tested this; Firefox, Safari and Chrome all do not display the image.

Comment: It was - I appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Open the images in Photoshop and resave in RGB color format (just incase it's CMYK).  Known issue in some legacy browsers, not sure when or if it went away.